# Extract raster value to polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, polygon, spatial-analyst

I am trying to extract raster values within multiple polygons. It would be nice if I could choose between say the maximum or an average raster value within the polygon.

For example, I have created depth grids as my raster to give the flood depth. Now I would like to calculate the highest/average raster value within each building footprint to estimate flood risk.

I have tried zonal statistics as recommended in a few similar posts, but the results are calculating uniform for every polygon instead of each individual building. I also have done polygon to point and extracted the rater value to the point, but in some cases the depth grid does not cross the center of the building footprint where the point is placed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Zonal Statistics as Table (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w8000000) for this type of operation.  The tool accepts both vector and raster data as input.  You can join the results to your input feature class if you wish.

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I was searching for! Thank you!